# Markdown Title + Image + Url + Url preview

Tags: php, markdown, telegram-bot

I'm using PHP to send a message with a specific template to users who have started a conversation with my telegram bot. I have set "markdown" field in PHP telegram send message API.

It's possible using markdown to have the following "template":

```
"MY_CUSTOM_TITLE"  
"MY_CUSTOM_IMAGE"  
"MY_LINK_CONTENT_PREVIEW"
```

All of this information has to be "wrapped" into a link, `MY_LINK`.

I have already tried the following strings:

```
"[MY_CUSTOM_TITLE](MY_CUSTOM_IMAGE_URL)(MY_LINK)"
"[![MY_CUSTOM_TITLE](MY_CUSTOM_IMAGE)](MY_LINK)"
```

Right now I'm using this string:

```
"[MY_CUSTOM_TITLE](MY_LINK)"
```

It produces the message in the image I have attached to this thread. I 
What I want is to customize the "amazon" setting a URI of a custom image keeping the link content text previre ("Online shopping from the earth's biggest selection of books, magazines, music, DVDs, videos, electronics, computers, software, apparel & accessories..." in the image I have attached).

[image]

Comment: What flavor and/or what parser are you using for your markdown? This may affect the answer.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the question.  
To be more clear, i use Telegram PHP Api to send message to a bot subribed users.  
In send message API i can set the "markdown" flag.  
So telegram itself parserize the "markdown text message".

Comment: Are you using a Library or you're doing everything from scratch? Anyway, I develop Telegram Bots and I've never seen that is possible to edit link previews. Can you add a link to Telegram documentation about this? Or, at least, a link to the documentation of the library you're using.

Comment: This is the library i'm currently using https://github.com/Eleirbag89/TelegramBotPHP

Comment: I found a workaround until a better solution:  
i have set parse_mode to "html" and then i have used html telegram syntax, it seems to work.